# To redirect or to display a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user who can have 0 to many business.

I want to display:

- the new business page if the user hasn't created any businesses or
- the show business page if they have 1 business or
- the business index page if there is more than 1 business.

Where should I put this logic? in the view or in the controller?

eg in the controller:

```
if !@user.businesses.any?
redirect_to new_user_business_path(@user)
elsif @user.businesses.count == 1
redirect_to business_path(@user.businesses.first)
elsif @user.businesses.count > 1
redirect_to businesses_path(@user)
end
```

or in the view:

```
<% if !@user.businesses.any? %>
<%= render partial 'no_businesses' %>
```

etc

It doesn't seem right in the view but I thought it would be good to ask for best practice.

Comment: it should be in controller only!

Comment: from which page or controller action are you trying to to this?

Comment: from which page/situation you want to display this details?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: its not matter of rails version, its matter of MVC ARchitecture

Comment: Rails 4 use `before_action`, Rails 3 `before_filter`, i think that it would be helpful to know the version to know which method use.

Comment: yes your are correct, but I am not familiar with rails 4. any way before_filter will be the best place to put the logic

Comment: Im using rails 3. All 3 answers below were helpful. Thanks everyone!! Not sure how to mark an answer as correct in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If the logic can't be separated from the main flow, it can be put into *view* as a feature of the main stream. If the logic is a apart of the other one, the code controlling the logic shall be put to a *controller*, or in case the code is too big, into *controller*'s helper.

So you the code if just a part of the main view, i.e. has no `else` statement, or if it has `else` statement, but has non-significant changes or renderings, logic can be put into the view as its part:

```
<% if !@user.businesses.any? %>
<%= render partial 'no_businesses' %>
<% end %>
```

If you have the `else` statement, and it has significant changes against to main action view, put the logic into contoller, and generate the two views for the each of cases.

**But** exactly for your case I would put the logic or controller's helper, and used it inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You want the view based logic if your user will be looking @ the same url, and just see a different view based on some logic( e.g number of businesses they have )

```
http://www.application.com/home
```

If the above applies to all of them ( which in my honest opinion should not ), then put the logic in the view.

If you want separated URLs, then put it into the controller, as you have specified in the above.

```
for user with no business: http://www.application.com/businesses/new
for user with 1 business: http://www.application.com/**business_name**
for user with many businesses: http://www.application.com/user/1/businesses
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it suite for you,

in  `business` controller add a before filter and put your logic,

```
before_filter :check_status

private
    def check_status
        if @user.businesses.blank?
          redirect_to new_user_business_path(@user)
        elsif @user.businesses.count == 1
          redirect_to business_path(@user.businesses.first)              
        end
    end
```